# EOF error with raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, qpython

I'm using `qpython` and when I'm using `raw_input` function I'm getting an EOF error, for example -

```
print " what's ur name",
a = raw_input()
print " hello %r"%a
```

and I'm getting this result -

```
what's ur name ?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 2, in 
  a= raw_input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

What's the problem ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Why is raw_input() missing? Any other alternatives?](http://qpython.org/question/89/why-is-raw_input-missing-any-other-alternatives/) from QPython forum:

> The raw_input function does not work because there is no console mode
>   like the pc in QPython+. But there is another methord to get users
>   input, you can do Kivy programming, it offer the UI support, and you
>   can get user input by using it's dialog or other input method.

Comment: Damn, wanted to fix the typo but it's a quote from the forum post ;)

Comment: @icedwater, Feel free to fix it. Just add note about the fix.

Comment: Nah, it's a direct quote so I should keep it there. Just commenting. It's minor, but stuck out like a sore thumb to me :P

Answer (score 0):

Please add "#qpy:console" to let your script run with console, which you can use raw_input correctly.

more about the user mode

http://wiki.qpython.org/doc/program_guide/